# Wait for execution in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var names = new Array();

    names[0] = 'jimit';
    names[1] = 'vinod';
    names[2] = 'vineet';

    for( var x in names){
        console.log(names[x]);
    }
    window.reLoad();


});
```

In the above code I want to wait till my for execution completes and then call window.reLoad();

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The above code is in callback function of an ajax request will this make a difference??

Comment: why are you overwriting you first array element for two times in a row after its definition? is it intended?

Comment: OK, you probably expect that you see three log outputs before reLoad() is called? That just doesn't happen because you store into the same array slot three times. If this is not the problem, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Lucius $alienhard Sorry i didnt want to add to same array slot edited my question

Comment: Looks like it is already the way you want it. What is your problem?

Comment: @Felix the window.reLoad() doesn't wait till "for" loop completes

Comment: @jimy: Why not? It is sequential code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function (){
var names = new Array();

    names[0] = 'jimit';
    names[1] = 'vinod';
    names[2] = 'vineet';

    for( var x in names){
    console.log(names[x]);
    }

    window.location = location.href;
})
```

OR

```
$(function (){
    var names = new Array();

    names[0] = 'jimit';
    names[1] = 'vinod';
    names[2] = 'vineet';

    for( var x in names){
    console.log(names[x]);
    }


    setTimeout( reloadWindow, 2000 );

})

function reloadWindow(){

    window.location = location.href;

}
```

Comment: your code is working but i have this in a callback function of an ajax request will this make any difference ????

Comment: @jimy well, it won't make any difference. just make sure you do your things before you redirect. If on same page, i recommend you to update page (using js) rather then redirect.